# How many mutawatir hadis?

Tags: uloom-al-hadith

Reading from the thread [How many ahad hadith are there in Sahih Bukhari?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/14518/how-many-ahad-hadith-there-in-sahih-bukhari)

and i searched other questions i want to know how many mutwatir hadis exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problematic question.

First, you have to define what's a *mutawatir* hadith?  The scholars differ tremendously.

Second, from that definition only then we can identify *mutawatir*.  But that's IF you can define it.

And this is also the reason why scholars give different numbers on how many *mutawatir* narrations exist.

No early *muhadith* from the first two generations believed in *mutawatir*. It was only later scholars that began the categorization of a *hadith* into *ahad* and *mutawatir*.

Realistically, with the all the definitions on *mutawatir* in existence, only **one** *hadith* can be said to be *mutawatir*

And ironically that *hadith* is =

> "Whoever tells lies about me deliberately, let him take his place in
>   Hell."

This *hadith* was reported by over a 100 sahaba and fits with majority of the definitions given to *mutawatir*.  Also, the word "deliberately" doesn't exist in some of the reports.

Imam ibn as-Salah has also mentioned similar in his book *"Muqaddimah"* about *mutawatir*