# Is the hadeeth your mother 3 times then you father sane or fabricated

Tags: hadith, source-identification, uloom-al-hadith

Abu Huraira may Allah be pleased with him, said: "A man came to the Messenger of Allah, peace be upon him said: O Messenger of God, from the people is good Sahapti ?, said: (mother), he said: Then who? He said: (mother), he said: then who? he said: (mother), he said: then who? he said: (father) agreed.

Answer (score 1):

This hadith is mentioned in the major hadith collections in many versions:

- In Sahih [al-Bukhari](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/78/2) and in his al-Adab al-Mufrad: [1](http://sunnah.com/adab/1/5) & [2](http://sunnah.com/adab/1/6).
- In Sahih Muslim: [1](http://sunnah.com/muslim/45/1) & [2](http://sunnah.com/muslim/45/2).
- In Sunan ibn Majah: [1](http://sunnah.com/ibnmajah/33/2) & [2](http://sunnah.com/urn/1328110).

all on the authority of abu Hurraira (May Allah be pleased with him).

---

A question or Note on your quote: the "agreed" which is in your Question may mean it's agreed upon by al-Bukhari and Muslim: For details see [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7864/what-are-the-terms-of-that-which-has-reached-tawatur). If this is the case this should already be a good sign for the authenticity of this hadith!

---

But there are similar narration on the authority of other sahaba (May Allah be pleased with them). For example:

- In Sunan [abi Dawod](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/43/367).
- In Jami' [at-Tirmidhi](http://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/27/1).

As they are also qualified as hassan they show that not only abu Huraira heard this hadith and give it a much better authenticity.

Other narrations which prolong the list are also available. For example:

- In Sunan [abi Dawod](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/43/368)
- In al-Adab al-Mufrad [1](http://sunnah.com/adab/1/3) & [2](http://sunnah.com/adab/2/1) of al-Bukhari

On the whole the hadith you mentioned seems to appear in most sunni hadith collections and seems to have a high degree of authenticity.

And Allah knows best!