# Did al-Bukhari and Muslim always follow their so called conditions?

Tags: hadith, uloom-al-hadith, sahih-bukhari, sahih-muslim, ilm-ar-rijal

In my answer on [What are the terms of that which has reached Tawatur?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7864/what-are-the-terms-of-that-which-has-reached-tawatur) I've tried to address the topic of the conditions of al.-Bukhari and Muslim.

I've also posted a related question: [What exactly are the conditions of al-Bukhari and Muslim?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/45275/what-exactly-are-the-conditions-of-al-bukhari-and-muslim)

I'm certainly not a scholar nor do I have deep knowledge in 'ulum al-Hadith.
But I suppose that the conditions of al-Bukhari and Muslim must either have been quoted by both in some of their books (not necessary in the books known as the sahihs ... the correct full title of what is known as sahih al-Bukhai is quoted in my answer here [Is Sahih al-Bukhari considered as 100% authentic by Sunni scholars?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/is-sahih-al-bukhari-considered-as-100-authentic-by-sunni-scholars)). Or later scholars have deduced them I strongly believe they were quoted by al-Bukhari and Muslim themselves.

But as I know that both of them have quoted ahadith of da'if narrators I'd like to know whether they always followed their own condition in their major works (I suppose all consider the both sahihs as such, as I'm at least aware of many other works of al-Bukhari) or did it occur that they added or quoted a hadith which doesn't follow their own conditions? (Is it possible to explain why?)

If so are these ahadith known, and what is their amount?

Comment: Al-Bukhāri and Muslim did not set any conditions themselves (presently known as _conditions of Al-Bukhari_ or _conditions of Muslim_). They were later deduced by scholars of hadith. What sort of scholarly opinions are you looking for? There are different opinions; it will be hard to capture all of them (in what would be termed as a "non-biased" answer). Hadith, like jurisprudence, have different schools. Would one school be enough, say that of Al-'Irāqi?

Comment: I am not clear what you mean by "both of them have quoted ahadith of da'if narrators". You mean in their sahihs? Or outside their sahihs? Are you referring to specific narrators like Hammad ibn Salama or Tamīm ad-Dāri, for instance? Or at large? If the topic is narrowed down, it will make it easier to answer.

Comment: @III-AK-III I've learnt that Qadi 'Iyad was among the first whom have deduced these conditions, but some say that Muslim indeed quoted his interpretation. My question came due to a hadith I've read lately which was commented "this is one of four ahadith where al-Bukhari didn't follow his conditions in his sahih". Your comments are constructive as, you made good points, unfortunately I can't answer them at this moment correctly. I've read that al-Bukhari for example quoted ahadith of some mubtadi'a (but not all of them, so he somehow picked out of their narrations, what he considered as safe)

Answer (score -2):

Yes, Imam al-Bukhari and Imam Muslim, the compilers of the two most authentic collections of hadith, Sahih al-Bukhari and Sahih Muslim, were known for their meticulous adherence to the conditions they set for accepting hadiths into their collections. They had strict criteria to ensure the authenticity and reliability of the narrations they included. These conditions included factors such as the reliability and integrity of the narrators, the continuity of the chain of narration, and the absence of any contradictions or discrepancies in the content of the hadith. They were known for their dedication to preserving the highest standards of authenticity in their collections.